# Casting to base via void*

Tags: c++

Is this undefined behavior?

```
class Derived: public Base //No other bases!!!
{
//...
};

Derived d;
void *pv = &d;
Base *b = static_cast<Base*>(pv);
b->SomeMethod();
```

In a sensible implementation, as long as there's single inheritance, the bits of a `Base` and `Derived` pointer would match. But does the language guarantee it?

EDIT: the Real Purpose™ is to pass a pointer to a polymorphic C++ object through a C layer back to a C++ callback. The object is created as Derived but consumed in the said callback as Base. The full story is [here](http://rathertech.blogspot.com/2014/03/seh-for-fun-and-profit.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding

> “In a sensible implementation, as long as there's single inheritance, the bits of a Base and Derived pointer would match.”

Yes for simple types, but **no** when base is non-polymorphic and derived introduces some virtual member.

So, a conversion `Derived*` to `void*` and then directly to `Base*` is Undefined Behavior not just pedantically formally, but also in practice.

---

In passing, the special cast `dynamic_cast<void*>( p )` gives you a pointer to the *most derived object* if the statically known type of `p` is pointer to polymorphic object.

This can be useful for example for use of hash tables like `std::unordered_map`.

---

Also in passing, possibly related to your Real Purpose™, the standard guarantees that a pointer to first member of a POD type can be cast to pointer to that type, and vice versa. This is in support of a C way to emulate inheritance.

Comment: Accepted for pointing out a concrete failure scenario. Filip's answer is OK, too.

Comment: The Real Purpose™ is served by replacing the second line with `void *pv = static_cast<Base*>(&d);`. In the specific case where I wrote/compiled/tested this and then started thinking, the base class had virtual methods all along.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, what you are doing does in fact invoke *undefined-behaviour*.

---

The standard mandates that casting from `T*` to `void*` back to `T*` is guaranteed to be safe, the latter `T*` will hold the same value as the original `T*`.

> 5.29 **Static cast** `[expr.static.cast]`
>
> > <sup>13</sup> <sub>...</sub> A value of type pointer to object converted to "pointer to cv void" and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall have its original value.
> >     `.

The above behaviour guarantees that `T * p = static_cast<T*> (static_cast<void*> (some_T_ptr))` will yield a value in `p` such that `p == some_p`.

---

In your example we are however casting from `void*` to a type related to the original `T`, but it's not the same exact `T`; this means that the result of the operation is unspecified.

The compiler is safe to assume that the address in the `void*` pointer (`pv`) originally points to a `Base` as a result it will not do any offset modifications to properly adjust to the fact that we are going from `Derived*` to `Base*`, and not `Base*` to `Base*`.

The compiler can simply copy the value of `pv` into `b`, when it really should adjust this value as it is coming from the address of a `Derived`.

```
Derived * pd = &some_derived;
void    * pv = static_cast<void*> (pd);
Base    * pb = static_cast<Base*> (pv); // unsafe
```

Comment: "casting from `T*` to `void*` back to `T*` is guaranteed to be safe" - but that's not what's happening here.

Comment: "equivalent of just casting from `Derived*` to `Base*` directly" - but it's the equivalent of `dynamic_cast` (ignoring any pointer adjustments), not `static_cast`, so not necessarily well-defined.

Comment: @MikeSeymour just realized this as I was looking for answers in the standard, I will update my post (including a temporary deletion).

Comment: @MikeSeymour are we more satisfied with the edit/rephrase of the post?